How do you change the default logging of JsonApiClient?
I am using the ServiceStack JsonApiClient to make service requests.
When the JsonApiClient encounters a non successful status code i.e. 500, it automatically (and rightly) logs at error level to my console or to the logs using the standard ILoggerFactory like so:
fail: ServiceStack.JsonApiClient[0]
      SendAsync: InternalServerError
      500 InternalServerError
Code: InternalServerError, Message: InternalServerError

My problem is that the same thing seems to happen when a 400 series error is encountered (as far as I am concerned - these are generally client issues, not server side issues).
fail: ServiceStack.JsonApiClient[0]
      SendAsync: NotFound
      404 NotFound
Code: NotFound, Message: NotFound

So if a GET request is processed, and the result is not found, I would expect that a valid response to the consumer of my API would be a 404. I really don't want / need this logged as an error, because it is expected behaviour.
This is the code (minimum viable reproduction of the problem) I used in a standard ServiceStack service to re-create this error - the same behaviour happens if this happens across services, and the error is logged by the JsonApiClient in the first service method. Both the requests and the responses have no implementation - the request implements IReturn<TResponse> and the response implements IHasResponseStatus and IHasStatusCode
public async Task<TestGetResponse> Get(TestGetRequest request)
{
  JsonApiClient client = new JsonApiClient("http://localhost:8080");
  Task<TestGetRequest2> response = client.SendAsync<TestGetRequest2>(new TestGetRequest2());
            
  return new TestGetResponse { StatusCode = 200 };
}

public async Task<TestGetResponse2> Get(TestGetRequest2 request)
{
  return new TestGetResponse2 { StatusCode = 404 };
}

My question is - how do I stop the JsonApiClient from logging at error level for 400 series response codes? Ideally, I'd still like to log these, but at a different level (maybe info or warning).
I've tried hooking into the ExceptionFilter by adding a delegate to this method, but I don't seem to be able to affect the logging (unless I am doing something wrong!).
My logs are getting flooded with a lot of noise in a busy production system, and 'real' errors (the 500 series errors) are getting obfuscated.
Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.

Haven't you looked at logging page yet?

I don't get why to use that if you can just pickup HttpClient + ILogger interface, and add any logging provider you want. You can create typed httpclient with proper contract and logging quite quickly.

Imo, you have chosen wrong building blocks.

@Ryan Yes, but that isn't helpful. The JsonApiClient seems to be doing this logging itself, and there is nothing in that page that tells me how to change the logging behaviour of the JsonApiClient. I don't want to change the logger itself - there is nothing wrong with that.

@Ryan Please can you clarify what you are basing your suggestion on? If you use the ServiceStack framework - the JsonApiClient is the correct 'building block' to use as per the documentation. I know I could use the HttpClient and engineer a service transport layer of my own, but I'm not about to re-write a working enterprise system just to fix a couple of lines of logging, I'd rather try to solve the problem using the recommended tooling for the framework I am using.

Oh, that's another deal, if you are working with large codebase. Let me search something for that.

@Ryan - if you are not familiar/very experienced with ServiceStack, (and I appreciate that you are trying to help), but can I please can I ask that you leave it for someone who is.

All Exceptions in JsonApiClient are logged as errors with Exceptions where if you're using ASP .NET Core it will use ASP .NET Core's ILoggerFactory whose Exception logging is conceptually similar to:
var log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(JsonApiClient));
log.LogError(default(EventId), exception, message);

Which will allow you to use ASP .NET's Core logging filtering system to filter logging which is logged against the JsonApiClient type.
In addition you could use a decorator pattern to have JsonApiClient use a custom logger that you can control what get logs in your AppHost, e.g:
public override void Configure()
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new MyLoggingFactory(LogManager.LogFactory);
}

Where MyLoggingFactory just returns a custom logger for JsonApiClient, e.g:
public class MyLoggingFactory(ILogFactory source) : ILogFactory
{
    public ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        var log = source.GetLogger(type);
        return type == typeof(JsonApiClient) 
            ? new MyLogger(log) 
            : log;
    }
    public ILog GetLogger(string typeName) => source.GetLogger(typeName);
}

Your custom logger can inspect the Exception and error message to ignore logging, otherwise calls the underlying logging provider, e.g:
public class MyLogger(ILog log) : ServiceStack.Logging.ILog
{
    public void Error(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        if (IgnoreException(message,exception)) return;
        log.Error(message, exception);
    }
    public void Error(object message) => log.Error(message);
    public void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args) => log.ErrorFormat(format, args);
    public void Debug(object message) => log.Debug(message);
    public void Debug(object message, Exception exception) => log.Debug(message, exception);
    public void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args) => log.DebugFormat(format, args);
    public void Fatal(object message) => log.Fatal(message);
    public void Fatal(object message, Exception exception) => log.Fatal(message);
    public void FatalFormat(string format, params object[] args) => log.FatalFormat(format, args);
    public void Info(object message) => log.Info(message);
    public void Info(object message, Exception exception) => log.Info(message, exception);
    public void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args) => log.InfoFormat(format, args);
    public void Warn(object message) => log.Warn(message);
    public void Warn(object message, Exception exception) => log.Warn(message, exception);
    public void WarnFormat(string format, params object[] args) => log.WarnFormat(format, args);
    public bool IsDebugEnabled => log.IsDebugEnabled;
}


Looks promising - I'll try to implement as you suggest to override the logger specifically for the JsonApiCleint - I'll mark as the answer if it works :)

this is perfect - in your IgnoreException hook, I'm trying to cast to WebServiceException, and if it casts, I'm performing my own logic to ignore 404 responses. Thank you very much for this.
